# Python Selenium Click On Hover Button

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to click a button to initiate a file **download**. The button has hover-over functionality from what I have seen. I have tried clicking via all `find_element_by paths`.

HTML chunk of the page,

```
<button class="btn-retrieve ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only" id="sub_1:listPgFrm:j_idt6461:downloadBtn" name="sub_1:listPgFrm:j_idt6461:downloadBtn" onclick="new ice.ace.DataExporter('sub_1:listPgFrm:j_idt6461:downloadBtn', function() { ice.ace.ab(ice.ace.extendAjaxArgs({&quot;source&quot;:&quot;sub_1:listPgFrm:j_idt6461:downloadBtn&quot;,&quot;execute&quot;:'@all',&quot;render&quot;:'@all',&quot;event&quot;:&quot;activate&quot;,&quot;onstart&quot;:function(cfg){showProcessingMessage('Downloading'); return true;;}}, {node:this})); });return false;" style="margin-top: -4px;" role="button" aria-disabled="false"><span class="ui-button-text"><span>Download</span></span></button>
```

The button's class before hovering is,

```
"btn-retrieve ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only"
```

The button's class when hovering is,

```
"btn-retrieve ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only ui-state-hover"
```

Selecting the button via the developer window and copying over paths from

```
<span>Download</span>==$0
```

I get the following,

CSS path,

```
#sub_1\:listPgFrm\:j_idt6461\:downloadBtn > span > span
```

XPath,

```
//*[@id="sub_1:listPgFrm:j_idt6461:downloadBtn"]/span/span
```

Code I have tried,

```
dwnd = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='sub_1:listPgFrm:j_idt6461:downloadBtn']/span")
dwnd.click()
```

And,

```
button = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#sub_1\:listPgFrm\:j_idt6461\:downloadBtn")
download = driver.find_element_by_link_text("Download")
hover = ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(button).move_to_element(download)
hover.click().build().perform()
```

Comment: Can you provide the website url?

Comment: Can you at least share the page HTML?  Not a single element but the whole page?

Comment: I see. I'm not sure I can do something with that. maybe someone else will be able

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the **text-based locator:**

```
//button[.='Download']
```

Please check in the `dev tools` (Google chrome) if we have **unique** entry in `HTML DOM` or not.

**Steps to check:**

`Press F12 in Chrome` -> go to `element` section -> do a `CTRL  + F` -> then paste the `xpath` and see, if your desired `element` is getting **highlighted** with `1/1` matching node.

and you can click on it:

**Code trial 1:**

```
time.sleep(5)
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[.='Download']").click()
```

**Code trial 2:**

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[.='Download']"))).click()
```

**Code trial 3:**

```
time.sleep(5)
button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[.='Download']")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", button)
```

**Code trial 4:**

```
time.sleep(5)
button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[.='Download']")
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(button).click().perform()
```

**Imports:**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
```